# How do I automate a Data Flow task in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 (Community Version) and I am trying to automate a data flow task that moves an SQL input into a Flat File output.

I have tested that the task works manually however I cannot find anywhere how to automate the process, any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule a process that triggers your code/DTS. You can use SQL Server Agent, Windows Scheduler or other scheduler software.

If you are working with SSIS and your process is a DTS (I'm guessin it is because you mentioned "Data Flow Task"), then you can execute it using the command line with the [dtexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) program.

If you are using C#, Visual Basic or another programming language in Visual Studio, make sure to compile it as a Console Application so it generates an .exe file.

Finally schedule your program execution (either dtexec or the call to the .exe) in your scheduler software, with a custom timing (for example everyday at 7am, just weekends, etc.). Make sure to monitor the results afterwards!